# jquery dropping down input box does not work properly

Tags: jquery

I have created a small div on top of the page that contains a login text field. everything works fine excapt that when the page loads the text box shows up, however the way i want it to be is when the page loads it should not show up until i click the button bellow to drop it down. right now it works the other way round when it loads it show up and then i have to click it to close it. can some one help me solve this problem the following is my code

```
//JQuery

      $(".logbtn").click(function(){ 
      $("#loginbox").slideToggle("slow");
      $(this).toggleClass("active");

    });
```

// HTML

```
 <div id="log">

 <div id="loginbox">
 <form method="post" action="login.php">
   <p><input type="text" name="username"  value="username" id="usernamelog"/></p>
   <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/></p>  
 </form>

 </div>
 <a class="logbtn">Login</a>

 </div>
```

//CSS

```
div#log{
width:301px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:650px;
}


div#loginbox{
width:300px;
background-color:#efebee;
padding-left:10px;
top:2px;
padding-bottom:10px;
border-radius:5px;
       -moz-border-radius:5px;
       -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}


.logbtn{
 width:200px;
 background-color:black;
 padding:7px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:none` to your `div#loginbox` CSS rules. This will hide it initially and then your jQuery `slideToggle` call will display it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mBLcv/)**